# Не срабатывает метод focus в js (*)

Tags: javascript

Не работает метод `.focus()` у элемента `Input.(id="renameaction")`.

Вызывается в момент нажатия на кнопку `(div id="win_rename")`.

Этот элемент `(id="renameaction")` исчезает и появляется с помощью `display:none/display:block`.

После того как появляется (идет обращение к renameshow) он должен появляться и пользовательский ввод должен быть сфокусирован на этом элементе.

browser chrome, os win 7.

Срабатывает только в первый раз - при запуске, предполагаю, из-за наличия атрибута 
*autofocus*, если элемент скрыть и снова показать, то фокусировки на него не будет.

Как решить и что неправильно работает?

```
<div id="win_rename" value='' onmousedown='renameshow()'>Переименовать</div>
...
<input type='text'  autofocus style='display:none;border #000 solid 1px;' id="renameaction" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) rename();" value="null" >
...

  function renameshow(){
    disableactions();
    var rel = document.getElementById("renameaction");
    rel.style.zIndex = '5000';
    rel.style.display = 'block';
    rel.style.position = 'absolute';
    var el = document.getElementById("contentelementselected");
    if (!el) var el = document.getElementById("contentfolderselected");
    rel.style.width = parseInt(winquery[0].wincontent.style.width)-44;
    rel.value = el.innerHTML;
    winaction.elementid = el;
    rel.style.height=19;
    el.appendChild(rel);
    rel.focus();
}
function disableactions(){
    var back = document.getElementById("win_back");
    var open = document.getElementById("win_open");
    var openInExplorer = document.getElementById("win_openInExplorer");
    var copy = document.getElementById("win_copy");
    var paste = document.getElementById("win_paste");
    var filedelete = document.getElementById("win_delete");
    var rename = document.getElementById("win_rename");
    back.style.display='block';
    open.style.display='none';
    openInExplorer.style.display='none';
    rename.style.display='none';
    filedelete.style.display='none';
    copy.style.display='none';
    if  (copyobj=='null')
        paste.style.display='none';
    else
        paste.style.display='block';
    var addfav = document.getElementById("win_addfav");
    addfav.style.display='none';
    winaction.addfav.style.display='none';
}
```

Полный код: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/44864159/www.rar

Comment: Полный код лучше разместить на http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Он не будет на jsfiddle работать, там всё в одном файле - index.php и, помимо html, там есть php, только что попробовал - написало кучу ошибок.

Comment: @infar, вы пишете что у вас проблема в js, выкладываете в теле сообщения много js-кода, а когда доходит до фидла, то начинаете загружать php, зачем? Проблема ведь в js, так и загрузите на фидл только js. На вскидку может это решение поможет вам поставить фокус на поле: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10038850

Comment: Спасибо, если сделать так
  
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('renameaction').focus();
    }, 0);

то работает.